# Feedback property of Draggable widget is not animating

Tags: flutter, draggable, flutter-animation

I need to animate a `Draggable` widget while it is in motion. The animation depends on the global position coordinates of the widget being dragged. I've used a `Listener` to get the finger tap position but the problem is that the `feedback` widget of the `Draggable` widget is not updating with `setState`. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470230/how-to-update-draggable-child-when-entering-dragtarget-in-flutter), [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16212), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63466781/flutter-feedback-of-draggable-widget-does-not-animate-properly) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59487079/update-all-the-attached-widgets-with-the-dragged-widget-of-a-stack) link but none of them helped.
Here's the code to demonstrate my problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double x = 0, y = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Listener(
        onPointerMove: (opm) {
          setState(() {
            x = opm.position.dx;
            y = opm.position.dy;
          });
          print('(${x.floor()}, ${y.floor()})');
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Draggable(
            childWhenDragging: Container(),
            child: Container(
              height: 150,
              width: 150,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            feedback: Material(
              child: Container(
                height: 150,
                width: 150,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Center(child: Text('(${x.floor()}, ${y.floor()})')),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this case, the coordinates displayed inside the blue screen should animate but even after doing a `setState` they don't update. I tried using `AnimatedBuilder` but there was no difference. It would be really helpful if someone could provide me with some help or an alternative method for achieving this with the `Draggable` widget.

Comment: i tried `AnimatedBuilder` and it works just fine

Comment: Then maybe I made some mistakes trying to use it. Could you please share  your version of the code?

Comment: `feedback: AnimatedBuilder(...)` - btw `ValueListenableBuilder` should work as well but i did not tried that

Comment: If your solution is working then could you please post it as an answer so that I can verify it and mark as the right solution?

Comment: it was a quick fix and i already deleted the code - simply make `feedback` as `AnimatedBuilder` that builds `Material > Container > Center > Text`

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand this part fully but with [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink)'s help and with some documentations I was able to achieve this animation using the following code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  double x = 0, y = 0;

  AnimationController _controller;

  Animation animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);
    animation = Tween(begin: 0, end: 100).animate(_controller);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Listener(
        onPointerMove: (opm) {
          setState(() {
            x = opm.position.dx;
            y = opm.position.dy;
            _controller.value = 0;
          });
          print('(${x.floor()}, ${y.floor()})');
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Draggable(
            childWhenDragging: Container(),
            child: Container(
              height: 150,
              width: 150,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            feedback: AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: animation,
              builder: (_, __) {
                return Material(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 150,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Center(child: Text('(${x.floor()}, ${y.floor()})')),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please comment if you have any better way of doing this or if you'd like to add some extra information or explanations.

Comment: instead of `AnimationController` use `ValueNotifier<Offset>` and then remove `setState` and simply use `notifier.value = opm.position` - also `ValueListenableBuilder` is preferable in that case

Comment: I couldn't try that part. Will try to give you an answer soon.